# open failed: EPERM during saving PDF file

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, android-external-storage

**Context and problem:**

Im trying to save pdf file in external storage, but i'm getting the following error:
`Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`

**1)When user opens the app, permissions are checked:**

```
private fun initAndCheckPermissions() {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.logo_nuin_nomb_subt)
        scaledbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 140, 140, false)
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            // if permission is granted we are displaying a toast message.
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Permissions Granted..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            requestPermission()
        }
    }
```

```
fun requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            requireActivity(),
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ), PERMISSION_CODE
        )
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.size > 0) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1]
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Permission Granted..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    requireActivity().finish()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So, when user clicks a specific button in activity.. PDF file with text and image is generated:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    fun generatePDF() {
        var pdfDocument: PdfDocument = PdfDocument()
        var paint: Paint = Paint()
        var title: Paint = Paint()
        var myPageInfo: PdfDocument.PageInfo? =
            PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth, pageHeight, 1).create()

        var myPage: PdfDocument.Page = pdfDocument.startPage(myPageInfo)

        var canvas: Canvas = myPage.canvas

        canvas.drawBitmap(scaledbmp, 56F, 40F, paint)

        title.typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL)

        title.textSize = 15F

        title.color = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.purple_200)

        canvas.drawText("A portal for IT professionals.", 209F, 100F, title)
        canvas.drawText("Geeks for Geeks", 209F, 80F, title)
        title.typeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL)
        title.color = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.purple_200)
        title.textSize = 15F

        title.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
        canvas.drawText("This is sample document which we have created", 396F, 560F, title)

        pdfDocument.finishPage(myPage)

        val file: File = File(Environment.getExternalStorageState(), "GFG.pdf")
        pdfDocument.writeTo(FileOutputStream(file))
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "PDF file generated..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        pdfDocument.close()
    }
```

**Problem:**

The problem is that the line
`val file: File = File(Environment.getExternalStorageState(), "GFG.pdf")` is causing the following error:
`Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` is not a directory.

Comment: @CommonsWare All the tutorials that explain how to save a pdf in external storage, say that you have to use Environment.getExternalStorageState()...

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there a different way?

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` is a state. It is not a directory. My guess is that you are trying to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. However, you cannot write there on Android 11+. "Is there a different way?" -- use the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument`) and let the user choose where on the user's device or in the user's cloud storage you should place the user's PDF.